# What is a "Category" in lyx .module file?

Tags: lyx, modules

One can write his own `.module` file to instruct [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/)

```
[to] add specific features to your document
(such as, say, endnotes) or change the predefined appearance.
```

[source](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Concepts)

I noticed that inside the user directory one can find the `lyxmodules.lst` file where it lists the modules LyX can reach for, with the following "headers":

```
## "ModuleName" "filename" "Description" "Packages" "Requires" "Excludes" "Category"
```

My question is about the category. It should be written as

```
#Category: theorems
```

(for example, to be categorized under "theorems"). But inside the LyX gui I don't see any category, and so I am asking whether it is needed at all.

Moreover, what are the different categories that one can pass as an argument when writing a module file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Category" layout tag is defined as follows:

```
[string] The category for this style. This is used to group related
styles in the style combobox on the toolbar. Any string can be used, but 
you may want to use existing categories with your own styles.
```

See Help > Customization for more information.

Interpreting the above, take a look at the following screenshot. You can see the categories "List", "Sectioning", "Unnumbered", and "FrontMatter". For example, the "Description" layout is in the "List" category.

[image: layout combo box]

Comment: I had the feeling it is related to this drop-down categorization, it is just that I found out there in the net a `moudle` file that has "#Category: theorems" declared in it (as written in my original question). I guess the guy who wrote it down must have not been familiar with the correct arguments?

Comment: Or rather if I want to group a new environment inside the "reasoning" list then the category should be "theorems" and not "reasoning"?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct. I looked at one of LyX's theorem styles and the category is indeed "Reasoning".

Comment: All right then. That solves the confusion. Thanks!